# Indirect index and match problem formula in different named tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a cell where I want to get the tax% based on a criteria [image]

Coming from "Taxes", depends on manufacturer country, year of release and car type

I've tried to use search and index and its not working at all, I need the cell to check values in the manufacturer country, year of release and car type use these inputs go to the Taxes sheet and get the value

[image]

Comment: What formula have you tried using?

Comment: VLOOKUP(E5,INDIRECT(H5),2,0)

But I think I need the Index and MATCH instead of the vlookup  :(

Comment: How are the tax-values stored? is that a table? or for each Country a seperate table?

Comment: Manufacturer countries are in same sheet or individual sheet?

Comment: @MG92 the tax values are stored in a different sheet in the same workbook called Taxes as shown in the pic :(

Comment: @Harun24HR the Manufacturer countries are in same sheet

Comment: @MG92 yes for each country separate table in the sheet Taxes named (Table 1, Table 2 ..etc)

Comment: Take a look at the OFFSET() function. I generally try and avoid using INDIRECT() as it hard to debug, and can break Excel's dependency checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I start, I should come clean and say I am an evangelist for the OFFSET() function, and a mortal foe of INDIRECT().

Let's assume that the number of vehicle types (TRUCKS, SEDANS, ....) is the same for each country, ie 8. (If its not then that can be worked around with a bit more effort). You could put this number in a cell somewhere and use it when you need the number of types.

Also, let's say the first column in your screenshot is column A. And that the cell A1 contains "China".

Let's say we are looking for the tax rate in 2009, for SEDANS in France.

Function 1:

```
=MATCH("France",$A:$A,0) will return 14 (if I have counted correctly)
```

... ie cell A14 contains the word "France".

On the assumption that the years are the same for all countries we can use any of the header rows to find the right column.

Function 2:

```
=MATCH(2009,$3:$3,0)-1 will return 8 I think.
```

If your years are just strings of text, then replace 2009 with "2009".

Because your Types are not in the same order in each table (why?) we need an extra step.

Function 3:

```
=MATCH("SEDANS",OFFSET($A$1,(Result of f1) -1 + 3,0,8,1),0) should return 3.
```

What is the maths in the OFFSET function? I need to go down (14-1) rows from cell A1 to get to "France". From there I need to go down another 3 rows to get to the first of the list of Types, and there are 8 types to search in. I'm then looking at a range of cells which is 8 rows x 1 column.

Now you can extract your tax rate, using

Function 4:

```
=INDEX(OFFSET($A$1,(Result of f1) -1+3,1,8,100),(Result of f3),(Result of f2))
```

(I've put 100 as I don't know how many columns of years you have. You could use something like =COUNTA($3:$3)-1 if there was nothing else in the 3rd row after the last date).

I would put the results of each function in a cell while you test this. Once you are happy that each step is working correctly you can nest all the various functions together, or alternatively just put some extra columns on the right hand side of your results table, which you can Hide if you want to.

EDITED: To add some $ on cell references to lock the "origin" of the data.

Comment: Thank you so much, but the last function is not working 

=INDEX(OFFSET((W5),1,8,100),(Y5),(Y5))

Comment: Ooops. I missed the first OFFSET parameter, which is the cell you want to start from. It should read:
=INDEX(OFFSET(A1,(Result of f1) -1+3,1,8,100),(Result of f3),(Result of f2)). I've edited the answer.

Comment: Also, in you have Y5 and Y5 in your formula... this would mean that the row and column you are looking at are the same? That is probably not what you want.

Comment: Edited to lock the cell A1 as $A$1 otherwise the origin will move if you copy & paste formulas.

Comment: Thank you so much, only one thing, F2, doesnt work when I refer to cell where I have the release year, is there any workaround for this  :(

Comment: It depends if your release year is a number, 2010, or a string "2010". You have to search the same datatype as in your per-country tables. You can convert numbers to strings using =TEXT(), and strings to numbers using =VALUE().

Comment: I've tried this, but its not working :( 

=INDEX(OFFSET(Taxes!B1,(MATCH(L5,Taxes!B1:B90,0)) -1+3,1,8,100),(MATCH(H5,OFFSET(Taxes!B1,(MATCH(L5,Taxes!B1:B90,0)) -1 + 3,0,8,1),0)),(MATCH(I5,China[[#Headers],[2002]:[2018]],0)))

and tried the TEXT one but its not wokring 

=INDEX(OFFSET(Taxes!B1,(MATCH(L5,Taxes!B1:B90,0)) -1+3,1,8,100),(MATCH(H5,OFFSET(Taxes!B1,(MATCH(L5,Taxes!B1:B90,0)) -1 + 3,0,8,1),0)),(MATCH(TEXT(I5),China[[#Headers],[2002]:[2018]],0)))

Comment: You know that I cant see your spreadsheet don't you? And so your cell references mean nothing to me? ;-)  TEXT() takes 2 parameters: the value you want to convert and a formatting string. Use TEXT(I5,"0") to convert a number to a string. You really do need to break down the individual function calls and make sure they are working before you nest them all together.

Answer (score 1):

If your tax tables are real **Tables**, each **NAME**'d with the name of the respective country, you can use something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(H13,INDIRECT(H12),MATCH(TEXT(H14,"0"),INDIRECT(H12 & "[#Headers]"),0))
```

where

- `H12` contains the name of the country
- `H13` contains the Type of vehicle
- `H14` contains the Year

eg:

[image]

- You'll need to adapt this to your real ranges, but this provides an approach.
- I'd suggest using dropdown lists (from Data Validation) in `H13:H14` in order to avoid typos.

If you want to avoid using Tables and also the volatile functions `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` (because if you have a lot of volatile functions they can impair performance of your worksheet) you can try the non-volatile, but longer and more obscure:

```
=VLOOKUP($H$13,INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($H$12,$A:$A,0)):INDEX($D:$D,LOOKUP(2,1/($A:$A<>""),ROW($A:$A))),$H$14-2000,FALSE)
```

In the above, you'll have to make adjustments

Assumptions are:

- The country name is above the relevant tax table
- Tax table starts in Column A

  - Change references to Column A if it does not start there.
  - Change the reference to Column D to the last column of your tax table (or even further if you will be expanding it).
- The Year columns are labelled the same for all countries (eg: consecutive years starting at 2002)
- `$H$14-2000` calculates the column argument for the `VLOOKUP` function.